# Discrete vs Countability

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that every discrete set of real numbers is countable?  What about the converse? Discrete set means every member of the set is an isolated point.
Thanks

Comment: The converse does not hold. Consider the set of rational numbers.

Comment: Thanks. How do you prove the statement  "every discrete set of real numbers is countable"

Comment: I would start by trying to cover the points of the discrete set with pairwise-disjoint open intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rob Arthan's answer is along the right lines - find an injective way to attach a rational number to each element of $X$, and then use the fact that $X$ is countable - but as AJ Stas' comment points out, the situation is actually a bit trickier.

Here's one way to carry out the argument. Suppose $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is discrete.

> Claim: For every $x\in X$, there is some rational $q_x$ such that $\vert x-q_x\vert<\vert y-q_x\vert$ for every $y\in X$ with $y\not=x$ - that is, $x$ is the closest element of $X$ to $q_x$.

Proof sketch: Let $p_i=x+2^{-i}$. If for every $p_i$, there is some $y_i\in X$ with $y_i\not=x$ but $\vert y_i-p_i\vert\le\vert x-p_i\vert$, then what can you say about the sequence $(y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$? Why does this contradict the assumption that $X$ is discrete?

---

Assuming that you've proved the claim, the map $x\mapsto q_x$ is injective; since the rationals are countable, this implies that $X$ is also countable.

NOTE: You might object, "But you haven't actually told me how to find $q_x$ - there might be (in fact, there *will* be) many rationals satisfying the required property!" This is true, but it's not a problem: since the rationals are countable, let $\{r_i: i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a list of all the rationals, and let $q_x=r_i$ iff $i$ is the least natural number such that $$\forall y\in X\setminus\{x\}, \vert x-r_i\vert<\vert y-r_i\vert.$$ This now gives a perfectly well-defined injective map from $X$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. This sort of detail is often swept under the rug.

Comment: To test your intuition: note that this argument really uses the assumption that $X$ is **discrete**. There is a similar-sounding property, **nowhere dense** - a set $X$ is nowhere dense if, for every open interval $(a, b)$ (with $a<b$), there is some $(c, d)\subseteq (a, b)$ (with $c<d$) such that $(c, d)\cap X=\emptyset$. Do you think that every nowhere dense set is countable? (Think about it for a while before you google the answer!)

Comment: Thanks for the question and the answer! Does the one way argument hold for all discrete sets i.e. are all discrete sets countable?